# And operator in Hibernate (lucene) search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using the following code for   search using hibernate-search. But this tokenizes the search query and does an **OR search**, whereas I want to do an **AND search**. How do I do that?

```
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    String searchQuery = "test query";

    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Customer.class).get();

    TermMatchingContext onFields = qb.keyword().onFields("customer.name","customer.shortDescription","customer.longDescription");

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = onFields.matching(searchQuery).createQuery();

    FullTextQuery persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Customer.class);

    List<Customization> result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Customer.class).get();
TermMatchingContext onFields = qb.keyword().onFields("customer.shortDescription",  "customer.longDescription");

BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> bool = qb.bool();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = null;
String[] searchTerms = searchQuery.split("\\s+");
for (int j = 0; j < searchTerms.length; j++) {
   String currentTerm = searchTerms[j];
   bool.must(onFields.matching(currentTerm).createQuery());
}

query = bool.createQuery();

FullTextQuery persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Customer.class);
resultList = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The **OR** logic is the default for Lucene. You can use a boolean DSL query as described here - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl, however, that might not solve your problem yet, because you seem to have both query terms in a single string. Depending on your usecase (if for example the search string is provided by the user) it might be better to get the Lucene query from the Lucene query parser.

Comment: thanks for the link. It helped me solve the problem. Will post my solution in a while.